# jQuery Slider - Multiple sliders with different handles

Tags: jquery, input, slider, range

I am using several jQuery sliders as user inputs.

Each slider (1) is created by (2) and they work perfectly.

1. `div class="slider" id="a_unique_identifier_for_this_slider"> /div>`
2. `$(document).ready(function() { $(".slider").slider();});`

The issue I am having is that I would like for each unique slider to have a unique handle (image, shape or etc). This could be stylized in the jquery-ui.css, but it alters all my slider handles.

Is there any way that I can define several "handle styles" and then attribute them to the sliders I want?

Thanks,
Clinton

Comment: Can't you use parameters with the `.slider()` plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your `$(document).ready(function() {})` code block:

```
$(".slider").slider();
$('#a_unique_identifier_for_this_slider .ui-slider-handle').eq(0).addClass("ui-slider-handle-some-unique-class");
```

This adds a css class for one of the sliders. You can do this for every slider. The css is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to remove the class that applies the handle styles and add your own custom class.

```
var sliders = $(".slider");
sliders.slider();
sliders[0].removeClass("classNameSpecifyingTheHangle").addClass("YourNewClassName");
```

untested.. but this should be the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS specific to your slider div

```
#a_unique_identifier_for_this_slider span.ui-slider-handle { background: red; }
```